# Wordpress simple datalayer plugin. Error with datalayer not defined

Tags: php, wordpress, google-datalayer

My main goal is to build a very simple datalayer plugin and push simple data into a window object called 'dataLayer' and when I go and type in window.dataLayer I should see  is 
[image: Ideal result].

I'm fairly new to PHP and am reaching some stumbling blocks.

I've found a code reference (https://github.com/framedigital/woocommerce-order-datalayer/blob/master/DataLayer.php) of a datalayer implementation that seems like a nice approach, so I went about breaking it down and stripping everything out I don't need except the bare essentials.

My code so far...

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Plugin Name: Ultimate DataLayer
 * Plugin URI: https://google.com.au
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: James LeBoeuf
 * Author URI: https://google.com.au
 * Description: Pushes stuff to datalayer
 * Requires at least: 4.0
 * Tested up to: 4.8
 *
 *
 * @package Ultimate Datalayer
 * @category Datalayer
 * @author James LeBoeuf
*/

class DataLayer {
  protected static $_instance = null;

  public $dataLayer = [];

  public function __construct() {
    console_log('inside __construct function');
    add_action('wp_head', [ $this, 'init' ], 5);
  }

  public function init() {
    console_log('inside init function');
    $this->setupDataLayer();
    $this->addToWPHead();
  }

  public static function instance() {
    console_log('inside instance function');
    if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
  }

  public function output() {
    console_log('inside output function');
    $dataLayer = apply_filters('ultimate_datalayer', $this->dataLayer);
    console_log('inside output function $dataLayer', $dataLayer);
    if (!empty($dataLayer)) {
      $encodedDataLayer = json_encode($dataLayer);

      console_log($encodedDataLayer);

      $scriptTag = '<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">dataLayer.push( %s );</script>';

      console_log($scriptTag);

      echo sprintf($scriptTag, $encodedDataLayer);
    }
  }

  private function setupDataLayer() {
    console_log('inside setupDataLayer function');
    $this->dataLayer['test'] = 'test';
  }

  private function addToWPHead() {
    console_log('inside addToWPHead function');
    add_action('wp_head', [ $this, 'output' ], 30);
  }

}


function dataLayer() {
  console_log('inside dataLayer function');
  return DataLayer::instance();
}


function console_log( $data ) {
  echo '<script>';
  echo 'console.log('. json_encode( $data ) .')';
  echo '</script>';
}


add_action('init', 'dataLayer');

?>
```

What seems to be happening is that the dataLayer doesn't seem to be defined and is throwing a console error on the chrome inspector console screen. Please find attached screenshot.

[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a catch in the script on the `public function output()`

`if (!window.dataLayer) window.dataLayer = [];`

Full example...

```
public function output() {
  console_log('inside output function');
  $dataLayer = apply_filters('ultimate_datalayer', $this->dataLayer);
  console_log('inside output function $dataLayer', $dataLayer);
  if (!empty($dataLayer)) {
    $encodedDataLayer = json_encode($dataLayer);

    console_log($encodedDataLayer);

    $scriptTag = '<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript"> if (!window.dataLayer) window.dataLayer = []; dataLayer.push( %s );</script>';

    console_log($scriptTag);

    echo sprintf($scriptTag, $encodedDataLayer);
  }
}
```